# Error when run MPJ in Netbeans

Tags: mpj-express

When I run MPJ program in Netbeans,here is exception:

```
[MPJRun.java]:[MPJRun.java]:MPJ_HOME environment found..
   java.lang.Exception: [MPJRun.java]:MPJ_HOME environment found..
       at runtime.starter.MPJRun.<init>(MPJRun.java:155)
       at runtime.starter.MPJRun.main(MPJRun.java:1238)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Please include more information about the situation surrounding the generated error.  How did you load the program, where did you run it from, did you follow a walkthrough and if so where did it break down?

Comment: Hi wolffrt-east.i  import MPJ bibrary, configure VM options is
 -jar /path_toMPJ/lib/starter.jar -np 4
i run java file with run button of NetBeans, not in command line.

Comment: @TạBáTrung Did you set environment variable MPJ_HOME? You need to set it first before running java code.